# How to read ntfs partition with ntfw

Tags: c, linux, ntfs, nftw

I use grub and put one distro tinycore linux on windows partition(c:/).I don't know why ntfw doesn't read this partition(sda1).I use this partition(in memory).
Below is the code and without "FTW_MOUNT" it will fail

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEVEL 1

int show(const char* path, const struct stat* st, int flags, struct FTW* ftw) {
    if (ftw->level > MAX_LEVEL)return 0;
    printf("path : %s mode : %o flag : %d\n", path, st->st_mode,flags);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    if(nftw("/mnt", show, 10,FTW_MOUNT | FTW_DEPTH | FTW_PHYS) != 0){
        printf("error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the result(sdb5 is linux)

```
tc@box:/tmp$ ./walker
path : /mnt/sdb1 mode : 40755 flag : 5
path : /mnt/sdb3 mode : 40755 flag : 5
path : /mnt/sdb5 mode : 40755 flag : 5
path : /mnt/sdb2 mode : 40755 flag : 5
path : /mnt mode : 40775 flag : 5
```

This is my grub menu.lst from drive c:

```
title Tiny Core 8
kernel /boot/vmlinuz tce=sda1
initrd /boot/tiny.gz
```

Comment: Is the filesystem mounted directly on `/mnt`?

Comment: Yes,i run the code from sda1,is that the problem?

Comment: What does that have to do with what I asked?

Comment: Yes, mounted on sda1(c:\), and  i use in memory.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that you put TinyCore Linux in the NTFS partition? Unless you have a large disk image saved as file, like Puppy Linux does, that is not really possible.

Comment: @Andrea Lazzarotto,Tiny core can save home directory and you just need to create tce directory on any partition and put the necessary files